# How to test a linux kernel upgrade inside a Container

Tags: linux-kernel, docker, upgrade, container, testing

As I know **Docker** uses host OS kernel, there is no custom or additional kernel inside container. All containers which run on a machine are sharing this "host" kernel.

Working with a containerized testing environment. Is There is a way to perform the  kernel upgrade test in such case?

Comment: What do you understand by `kernel upgrade test`?

Comment: I am working on automating the OS updates and the kernel is part of this process. I want to create some unit tests that will run beforehand and verify that everything is okay. So, I want to test the kernel upgrade task. I am using docker.

Comment: Create virtual machine and test it there

Comment: The question is if there is another way but using docker

Comment: No, you use the same kernel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to perform some amount of kernel upgrade testing inside a container. Even though containers don’t run their own kernels, you can still install kernel packages inside containers, and upgrade them, so you can check that the *package* upgrades are correct.

However there is no way to verify that a kernel *boots* inside a container. To do that, you need some sort of VM, either emulated or virtualised (*e.g.* Qemu with or without KVM). You can also drive that from inside a container if you want, and if the host is set up to allow it. See [RancherVM](https://github.com/rancher/vm) for an extreme example (on Kubernetes).

Comment: Great !! Thank you Stephen